# Couldn't find my span tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I thought using closest goes up the DOM and find goes down the DOM isn't it?

I am trying to find a span element when an input has focusout.  I am able to get the value of the input when focusout properly but couldn't find the span.

in my html I have something like this

```
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="card-holder-name">Card Holder Name: <span>eafsdafasdf</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control card-holder-name" id="card-holder-name">
              </div>
```

in jquery

```
$(".card-holder-name").on('focusout', function(){
var inputValue = $(this).val();
console.log($(this).closest('label').find('span').text();
```

});

I tried using `console.log($(this).closest('label').text());` to just find the label but no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.closest()` *does* go up the DOM but you're trying to use it against a sibling.

Use `.prev()` in this case:

```
$(this).prev('label').find('span').text()
```

[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bv4s1u88/)

Comment: or `siblings('label')` if the markup could be changing

Comment: so closest wouldn't work with siblings? Also, I try not to use prev in case if there's some html changes so I heard using closest would be better.  But now seeing `prev('label')` does that mean prev would also travel up the siblings to find label? sryz I am only familiar with `prev()` didn't even know we can have inputs

Comment: It would, but you'd need to go up, at least to the div, and then back down. Your label isn't 'up' from your input, it's next to -- a sibling. `prev('label')` means select the previous element if it's a label. If you want to use closest instead of prev, use `$(this).closest('div.form-group').find('span').text()`

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, `$.closest()` traverses up the DOM and `$.find()` traverses down.  The issue you're having, however, is that `label[for='card-holder-name']` is a *sibling* to `input.card-holder-name`.

For the specific HTML you're using, you could either go with `$(this).prev("label")` or `$(this).parent().find("label")`.

Comment: looks like I was just a bit too slow to keep up with @j08691